# fillRect causes entire screen to change color

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, canvas

I have a webpage with an iframe in it, and within that iframe there is a canvas with id="canvas", when I call (from a .js file within the iframe) fillRect on the context of the canvas the entire web page (both inside and outside the iframe turns grey. How do I prevent this from happening?

This is my javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
```

This is my HTML within the iframe:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  </head>
  <body class="canvas">
     <canvas id="canvas" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
     <script src="game.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is the css styling (which both the iframe and the webpage with the iframe use):

```
*
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: scroll;
    padding: 0;
}
body
{
    background-color: #999999; /*This is the color the entire screen is turning*/
}
canvas
{
    height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 600px;
}
canvas>canvas
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I also find it annoying that the iframe can affect the webpage that it is in, the main reason I used an iframe was to isolate the  and javascript related to it isolated from the rest of the web page and it seems like it does not do that very well. How do I fix this bug and is there any way I can isolate the iframe so that it does not affect the rest of my webpage regardless of the javascript put into it or at least affects it as little as possible.

EDIT: I should also mention that if I remove ctx.fillRect() everything works as intended and the web page doesn't turn grey.

EDIT2: I should also mention that when I say turn grey, I mean as in the foreground turned grey and covered over every other element on the page (I have  tags and various other things in the main web page that contains the iframe, the only non-grey thing on the screen in the 100*100px black box, every piece of text / title / button etc. is covered up with grey.

EDIT3: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dannys-aws/public/High+Score+Master+1.zip is the page in question if you would like to test it yourself.

Comment: In which ways does the content of the iframe interact with your main webpage? Also there is a typo in your js, the method is `getContext()` (case senstitive).

Comment: I fixed the getContext(), in my javascript it was already getContext() I made the typo when copying it over. The content inside the iframe (javascript and <canvas> is making the background of my entire web page outside of the iframe turn grey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the overflow: auto; adding scroll bars to every element.

Comment: Let me rephrase my problem, the entire screen is turning grey as in it is overlapping all the other content on the screen such as <h1>'s and the like. It has gone from a background to a foreground. With the only non grey thing on the screen being the 100*100 black square.

Comment: can you provide a link to a demo? jsFiddle doesn't play well with iframes.

Comment: What's an easy way to do that?

Comment: You would need a public facing web server - I am sure there are free options around - ask Google.

Comment: Unfortunately it will take me a long time to put it up to a production environment as I would need to set up nginx, gunicorn as well as find an environment to host it so instead I will use HTTrack on the dev server and store it on amazon aws for people to download and test.

Comment: Turns out I am dumb and just pressing CTRL+S will save the webpage. Sorry I couldn't host it on a website but this will allow you to view it just fine: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dannys-aws/public/High+Score+Master+1.zip

Comment: I believe it is the `overflow: scroll` that is giving the illusion of everything having a gray background. its adding a scrollbar to every single element on the page. remove this, then there is no more white, and `background-color: #999999;` is setting everything to be grey. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks a ton man! Getting rid of `overflow: scroll;` and replacing it with `overflow: auto;` fixed the issue! I am still confused as to how that made the entire screen go grey though. Also can you edit your answer to explain that the issue was the `overflow: scroll;` so that I can accept the answer without being misleading.